# Connecting SQL server through SQLDMO

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, connection, sqldmo

I was able to connect to remote SQL server through SQLDMO residing my hosting server. There was no issue. Now as I've Just switched to the new hosting provider, I can connect to the database server through SQL server management studio but SQLDMO I cannot connect anymore.

Here is my VB.NET code:

```
    Dim oServer as New SQLDMO.SQLServer2
    oServer.EnableBcp = True
    oServer.Connect(pServer, pUserName, pPassword)
```

At third line an error pops up saying:

"[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance())."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check if you are using correct Data Source name in your connection string. If you are using localhost then try to use IP address of server. If you have SQL server with the Instance then use instance name with the server Ip in your connection string.

http://forums.esds.co.in/f4/dbnetlib-connectionopen-invalid-instance-invalid-connection-4139/

Comment: I'm not using any connection string. Just passing Server IP, user name, and password as parametrs to the command: oServer.Connect(pServer, pUserName, pPassword). Any how using instance name along with the server IP did the trick for me. Thanks a lot.